# How to set dynamic arguments for terraform resource

Tags: terraform

### Background

I am working to wrap a few resources into a module, and need to ensure that it is reusable.

Now working on a resource, lets all it mysql resource.

The terraform code of this module looks like this

```
resource "azurerm_mysql_flexible_server" "mysql" {
  # some arguments
  xx_id = var.xx_id
  # some other arguments
}
```

According to the document from Terraform, resource can have some arguments that is optional, which means if I don't set it terraform will consider it as not exists.

Now, I want to conditionally set the `xx_id`, when var.enabled is true, set xx_id from var.xx_id, otherwise don't set it.

### What I have tried

#### Set default value to ""

This equals to assign "", so not working.

#### Set nullable to true

Got this error message:

The argument "xx_id" is required, but no definition was found.

Answer (score 0):

```
variable "xx_id" {
  type        = string
  nullable    = true
  default     = null
}
```

As last when I try the above code, it works.

Looks like:

`nullable`: Allow to assign null, but in previous attempt no value assigned to it, so it will report error, because this variable is still required.
`default`: Set null to it as allow null.

Comment: `nullable` is `true` by default, so it doesn't do anything here. The (default) value `null` means that the default value of the resource will be used.